# Receiving 404 error after setting up mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a website locally on Ubuntu + Apache + Virtual hosts, but am having some problems customising urls with mod_rewite. First I was getting an internal server error, but then I found I had to turn mod_rewite on so I found this tutorial...

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

...swapping out their path names for my own.

My virtual hosts sites-available conf file codecourse.dev.conf...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName codecourse.dev
    ServerAlias www.codecourse.dev
    ServerAdmin admin@codecourse.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/codecourse.dev/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/codecourse.dev/public_html >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all      
    </Directory>
```

My .htaccess file which lives inside the public folder...

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /var/www/codecourse.dev/public_html/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My apache access log when trying to pass the url: codecourse.dev/public/home/index/Leon

```
192.168.0.105 - - [20/Nov/2015:08:30:32 +0200] "GET /public/home/index/Leon HTTP/1.1" 404 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Note: This access error only appears when passing a custom url. Otherwise accessing codecourse.dev/public works as expected.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, you have set your DocumentRoot in Virtualhost, remove RewriteBase or set it to `/public`.

Btw, for checking yourself you can add `R` flag to your `RewriteRule` and see, what url you get.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I see how RewriteBase works now. The R flag helped a lot.